# Enable/disable button on contentEditable keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a couple of divs on my website that utilize the HTML5 contentEditable attribute. The goal is for the user to be able to start writing a journal entry, and have the save button change from disabled to enabled.

Here's the HTML I have so far:

```
<div id="entry-create-partial">
  <div id="title-create-partial" name="title" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder='Title it' style="color:black"></div>
  <div id="content-create-partial" name="content" contenteditable="true" style="color:gray">Write anything</div>
  <button type="button" id="create-entry" class="btn" disabled="true">Save</button>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title-create-partial').keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).value == '') {
            $('#create-entry').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#create-entry').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

While this does work, it only checks on the first keyup; if the user backspaces and deletes everything they typed, the button doesn't disable itself again. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `<div>` element not an `<input>`, so use `text()` instead of `val()` (and be sure to trim so it isn't enabled on whitespace). Also could use `prop()` to set the property instead of `attr()`.

```
$('#title-create-partial').keyup(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === '') {
        $('#create-entry').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#create-entry').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BTCgU/)

Comment: I have to wait ~7 mins to choose it as the answer.